How to solve when I open the project it becomes dead pixels and the objects are destroyed with pink green black?
When I want to move the Geometry node tab to the layout screen suddenly like a dead pixel, then the object / model becomes destroyed with pink green black colors randomly.
This is not because the texture or shader is missing because they are still there. I don't know what the cause is. I have spent a lot of my time to make it.
Do I have to start over again? is there any other solution?






Please don't ask the same question twice.

Sorry, i didn't know that i posted how many times because i thought my question did not post yet

Please don't take photos of your computer screen! Bkender has a perfectly good built-in screenshot generator which you use from the Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender. It eliminates screen reflections and moiré patterns.

Update your graphics card driver

so i have to update my graphics card? ok thanks
